# Send Current HTML Dom , send via jquery ajax and save via php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to save the current dom of the document being worked on to the server via jquery.  But running into an issue trying to send the dom value to a php file which handles the save.  Here is the code :

**Jquery**

```
$('SaveQuote').click(function() {
var customername =  $('#customername').val();
var customernameedit = $.trim(customername);
var customerphone = $('#customerphone').val();
var quotedata = encodeURIComponent($(document).html());


$( "#Message" ).load("/include/SaveQuote.php? 
customername="+customernameedit+"&customerphone="
+customerphone+"&data="+quotedata);

});
```

**PHP Code**

```
$customername = $_GET['customername'];
$thedata = $_GET['data'];
$thephone = $_GET['customerphone'];


$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Quotes/'.$customername.$thephone.'.html';
// Open the file to get existing content
$current = $thedata;
// Append a new person to the file
file_put_contents($file, $current);

echo'Record Was Saved! View It Here <a href="/Quotes/"'.$customername.$thephone.'>
View Quote</a>';



?>
```

The Load Request is working and all the Values are "posting" but the load request is not allowing the dom to be sent via the quotedata var in the jquery code, could it be there is too much data in the string?

I believe I may have to use post with Jquery but not 100% sure.

The point of this snippet of code is to allow the dom during manipulation to be saved and viewed later or changed/edited, so I need the entire dom saved as is.  Also will implement an autosave eventually but not part of this question.

So simply, how do I send the current dom via jquerys ajax controls to my php save file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript could look like this:

```
$('SaveQuote').click(function() {
    var customername =  $('#customername').val();
    var customernameedit = $.trim(customername);
    var customerphone = $('#customerphone').val();
    var quotedata = $('html').html();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/include/SaveQuote.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            customername: customernameedit,
            customerphone: customerphone,
            data: quotedata
        }, success: function(response) {
            $("#Message").html(response);
        }
    });
});
```

That would make a POST request to the server with the data you want, and the server response would be injected as innerHTML into the `#Message` element.

Comment: tried the above code, changed the PHP file to $_GET to $_POST , the name and number are sent correctly but the body of the file is undefined.  Essentially the document contents are not being sent

Comment: Thats because `$(document).html()` is null. How about `$('html').html()`? And also I dont think you need to call `encodeURIComponent`.

Comment: the html worked but is missing the header information for css.  It appears my jquery is still functioning within though.  Removed the encodeURIComponet as well, you were right

Comment: $('html').html() should get any HTML there is to get.

Comment: scratch that, it was my mistake the custom css i had did not have a / in front of it we are good thanks!  The issue I am running into though is the values are not saved.  Shouldn't the modified data be carried over?  It is just reloading the quote form, meaning that it saves the html, but not the values

Comment: What do you mean by "the values are not saved"? Do you mean that your `file_put_contents` call isnt working as expected? And what do you mean by "modified data be carried over"? Your PHP code doesnt say anything about returning the HTML to the client. All it does is return a message with a link? Maybe the link should end in `.html`?

Comment: sorry I should clarify , the code works exactly.  But the expectation is that when someone types into an input box or a dropdown and then save the quote, these values are saved as well in the exact way that they typed it.  As the code is saving the dom, it is not saving the  modified fields just the default dom. I am assuming.  So If I put john joe in the input field in the saved html  file I am expecting that input field to have John doe, but it is blank.

Comment: Essentially everything is saved besides input and dropdownfields selected and inputed values

Comment: Ah. Something typed into an input box will never make it into the HTML. If you just want to save what theyve typed into a form, then youre probably better off saving those values explicitly using JS instead of relying on the entire page HTML, which will never include user input.

Comment: so much for the simple method, unless on change I change the selected value to that defaulted input.  Thanks for all your help @johnathanLerner